# SQL, get values from second table based on minvalue of grouped selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a query below were i list all transactions that hasnt been nulled, the objective is get to a list with all opened transactionID (represents a customerorder) and its invoicenumber.

```
Table 1
transactionID
bookdate
cost
year

Table 2
transactionID
invoice
year

SELECT 1.transactionID, Sum(cost), 1.Max(bookdate), 2.invoice
FROM 1
LEFT JOIN 2
ON 1.transactionID = 2. transactionID AND 1.year = 2.year
GROUP BY 1.transactionID, 2.invoice
HAVING (Sum(cost)<>0)
```

My problem is that the transactionID is reused every year, that's why I need to check that the year corresponds between the actual transactionID and the invoices in table 2.

Every transactionID has several transactions with different bookingdates. This mean that one transaction could have happened in 2011 and one in 2012. I want the query to look for the year that corresponds to the earliest bookingdate per open transactionID.

For example:

Table 1

```
1 | 20120101 | -20  | 2012
2 | 20120501 | -100 | 2012
2 | 20110501 | 100  | 2012
1 | 20110801 | 50   | 2011
```

Table 2

```
1 | invoice X   | 2012
2 | invoice Y   | 2012
1 | invoice old | 2011
```

The result should be

```
1 | 30 USD | Invoice old
```

Comment: Which database (and database version) are you using?

Comment: And which of the two tables is the master transaction table? Both have `TransactionID` but I guess one of them is dependent on the other. Honestly, it wouldn't hurt if you gave the tables meaningful names instead of `1` and `2`.

Comment: I guess Table 2 is the master and on table 1 the transactionID is the foreign key...correct? also, you haven't told wich RDBMS are you using, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgre, Oracle? And if you provide also some test data will be helpfull

Comment: Hi! SQL Server. 1 is master and the transactionID isnt a uniqe key in this case and can be used once every year.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later version, you could use [window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) functions like this:

```
WITH summedAndRanked AS (
  SELECT
    [1].transactionID,
    [2].invoice,
    totalCost    = SUM(cost)     OVER (PARTITION BY [1].transactionID),
    lastBookDate = MAX(bookdate) OVER (PARTITION BY [1].transactionID),
    rnk          = DENSE_RANK()  OVER (PARTITION BY [1].transactionID ORDER BY [1].year),
  FROM [1]
    LEFT JOIN [2]
      ON [1].transactionID = [2].transactionID
     AND [1].year = [2].year
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  TransactionID,
  totalCost,
  lastBookDate,
  invoice
FROM countedAndRanked
WHERE totalCost <> 0
  AND rnk = 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're nearly there - try

```
SELECT 1.transactionID, 1.Year, Sum(cost), Max(1.bookdate), 2.invoice 
FROM 1 
LEFT JOIN 2 
ON 1.transactionID = 2. transactionID AND 1.year = 2.year 
GROUP BY 1.transactionID, 1.Year, 2.invoice
HAVING (Sum(cost)<>0)
```

Comment: For every TransactionID they seem to want to retrieve only its earliest year's data. I guess, either a derived table or a ranking function call is in order.

Comment: Hi. Thank you

This didnt however work. I get all the transactionID listed correctly but I think its trying to find the invoice for the year that represents the last bookingdate. Then I wont get a hit at all as the invoice is registered with year-1 in this case in table 2.

Comment: @user1648738 I'm not sure I understand - perhaps editing the question with some sample data will provide more responses?

Comment: I'll take my comment back :) I think it actually work in a sense. However the problem is that when i add 1.year to my selection the query represents the transactionID twice if we have transactions on different years. I will edit the questions above with an example